# How to drop rows based on timestamp where hours are not in list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a large dataframe (several million rows) where one of my columns is a timestamp (labeled 'Timestamp') in the format "hh:mm:ss" e.g. "07:00:04". I want to drop the rows where the hour is NOT between or equal to 7 and 21.

I've have tried to convert the timestamps to strings and use slicing but I was not able to get it working and I believe there should be a more effective way.

```
# Create list of opening hours (these should not be droped)
opening_hour = 7
closeing_hour = 21
trading_hours = []
for hour in range(closeing_hour - opening_hour + 1):
    add_hour = opening_hour + hour
    trading_hours.append(add_hour)
```

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
      Date Timestamp      Close
0  20180102  07:05:00  12925.979
1  20180102  21:05:02  12925.479
2  20180102  22:05:04  12925.280
3  20180102  23:55:06  12925.479
4  20180102  06:05:07  12925.780
5  20180103  07:05:07  12925.780
[...]
```

I want to drop the rows with index 2, 3 and 4 (there are several thousand), so the result should be something like:

```
  Date Timestamp      Close
0  20180102  07:05:00  12925.979
1  20180102  21:05:02  12925.479
2  20180103  07:05:07  12925.780
[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can give your `DataFrame` a proper `DatetimeIndex` as follows:

```
dtidx = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Timestamp'].astype(str))
df.index = dtidx
```

and then use `between_time` to get the hours between hours 07 and 21 inclusive:

```
df.between_time('07:00', '22:00')
# returns
                         Date Timestamp   Close
2018-01-02 07:05:00  20180102  07:05:00   12926
2018-01-02 21:05:02  20180102  21:05:02 12925.5
2018-01-03 07:05:07  20180103  07:05:07 12925.8
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned about slicing and someone already mentioned about how to go with it, I would like to introduce you to extracting the hour using [dt.hour](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html)

First convert your date with type string to date with type datetime:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

You can now easily extract the hour part using [dt.hour](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
df['hour'] = df['date'].dt.hour
```

You can also extract year, month, second, and so on in a similar way.

Now you can do normal filtering as you would do with other dataframes:

```
df[(df.hour >= 7) & (df.hour <= 21)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the other answers which work with proper timestamp data types, but since you mentioned trying and failing with a string slicing method, it might be helpful for you to see a solution using string slicing that does work:

```
df['Hour'] = df['Timestamp'].str.slice(0, 2).astype(int)
df[(df['Hour'] >= 7) & (df['Hour'] <= 21)]
```

The first line creates a new integer column from the slice of the string which represents the hour, and the second line filters on said new column.

```
       Date Timestamp      Close  Hour
0  20180102  07:05:00  12925.979     7
1  20180102  21:05:02  12925.479    21
5  20180103  07:05:07  12925.780     7
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to use [`pd.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html).

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df.set_index('Timestamp').between_time('07:00:00', '21:59:59')
```

```
Timestamp           Date        Close
2019-07-22 07:05:00 20180102    12925.979
2019-07-22 21:05:02 20180102    12925.479
2019-07-22 07:05:07 20180103    12925.78
```