# Pandas dataframe datetime filter doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning how to work with pandas dataframe and trying to pre-process some data. I have a set of data showing the weather with datatime field as a string. Each day appears twice in this dataset with 00:00 hours and 12:00 hours. I am trying to filter it and keep only data with 12:00 hours. I tried some options recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57151142/how-to-drop-rows-based-on-timestamp-where-hours-are-not-in-list):

```
#pre-processing to get only required information
data = data[["date_time", "WindGustKmph", "humidity", "precipMM", "pressure", "tempC", "winddirDegree", "windspeedKmph"]]
print(data.head())
print(str(len(data)))

#set proper datatime index and keep only day time weather
dataIndex = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date_time'].astype(str))
data.index = dataIndex
#filter the data
data.between_time('07:00:00', '21:00:00')

print(data.head())
print(str(len(data)))
```

As a result, I see that an index was added, but the filter was not applied, and my question is why?

```
          date_time  WindGustKmph  ...  winddirDegree  windspeedKmph
0   2018-01-01 0:00             8  ...             21              4
1  2018-01-01 12:00            12  ...             79             10 
2   2018-01-02 0:00            14  ...             19              7
3  2018-01-02 12:00            18  ...             57             16
4   2018-01-03 0:00            19  ...             16              9

[5 rows x 8 columns]
2192
                            date_time  ...  windspeedKmph
date_time                              ...               
2018-01-01 00:00:00   2018-01-01 0:00  ...              4
2018-01-01 12:00:00  2018-01-01 12:00  ...             10
2018-01-02 00:00:00   2018-01-02 0:00  ...              7
2018-01-02 12:00:00  2018-01-02 12:00  ...             16
2018-01-03 00:00:00   2018-01-03 0:00  ...              9

[5 rows x 8 columns]
2192
```

Also, I tried another option:

```
data['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_time'])
data['hours'] = data['date_time'].dt.hour
data[data['hours'] != 0]
```

the same result. The column was added but without filtering data.

```
            date_time  WindGustKmph  ...  windspeedKmph  hours
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00             8  ...              4      0
1 2018-01-01 12:00:00            12  ...             10     12
2 2018-01-02 00:00:00            14  ...              7      0
3 2018-01-02 12:00:00            18  ...             16     12
4 2018-01-03 00:00:00            19  ...              9      0

[5 rows x 9 columns]
2192
```

Would appreciate any suggestion on what I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the filtered dataset back to `data`:

```
data = data.between_time('07:00:00', '21:00:00')
```

or (your second option)

```
data = data[data['hours'].between(7, 21)]
```

Comment: gotcha. thanks, it definitely helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! If it helped, can you please accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, new to this. accepted. Again, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like 7:00:00 and 21:00:00 comparisons.
Why don't you do just

```
data = data[data['date_time'].dt.hour == 12]
```